# How to free system resources/CPU usage on webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, effects

I am using this HTML Template: http://volar.makwan.net/index02.html

Many of my users are experiencing high CPU usage on their laptops and netbooks when viewing the website, Safari also gives this message when they are on the website for more than a few minutes: "This webpage is using significant energy. Closing it may improve the responsiveness of your Mac."

My first attempt at freeing up resources was to get rid of the flat surface shader effect when the user scrolls away form the home screen using this code:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  let home = document.getElementById('home-section');
  let effect = document.getElementById('fss');
  if(!isElementInViewport(home) && isVisible) {
    effect.style.display = "none"
    console.log("effects disabled in order conserve resources");
    isVisible = false;

  } else if(isElementInViewport(home) && !isVisible){
    effect.style.display = "block";
    isVisible = true;
  }

};
```

This worked quite well but there's other elements in the page that are still taking up A LOT of resources.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to disable the effects when they aren't in view/disable them after a certain period of activity on the website?

Comment: There is probably a memory leak. See the «performance/memory tab» of debugger. Take care of global var, empty variables when not in use. «Use strict» can help. You must see the garbage collector in action. I let you search this way. Of course it might be something else, like a loop that never end, or setIntervals, etc. Good luck!

Comment: I would disable the effect on the top simply after a few seconds. It's not that great so I would want it run my CPU at 100 % :)

Comment: @OndraŽižka - I did that with the JavaScript posted above, but it is still taking a lot of resources.

Comment: Are there filters that are close to 0 % opacity? Perhaps remove those when not needed.

Answer (score 2):

It's what you're doing in `fssinit.js`. `requestAnimationFrame` renders at 60fps. Fancy graphics, but it's also resource intensive.

Try slowing down `requestionAnimationFrame` using a `setTimeout` and see if it helps. If it does, then that's the origin of your problem. In `fssinit.js` try doing

```
function animate() {
  now = Date.now() - start;
  update();
  render();
  setTimeout(() => requestAnimationFrame(animate), 500);
}
```

If that makes things better, then that's your problem and should consider permanently keeping that `setTimeout` with a lower delay or change some of those calculations you're making

Answer (score 1):

First of all, open up a Task Manager to see the CPU. Close other resource-hungry apps to see a clear picture; your CPU usage should be as flat as it can be before you open the page.

Now open it.
Boom!, it goes up to, like, 50%. (Mine actually jumped up to 95%)

On the top of your page, there's that big red animated area. It takes the whole screen. Now right-click somewhere around it and choose "Inspect element" from the menu. You'll see the source now, it's called *"home-section"*, that's the id of a <section> tag. Right click on it in the source, and choose "Delete". (I usually just hide them first, to see if it's only a rendering thing; this one is not.)

So, **Delete element**.

Aaand, the CPU is breathing again!

So there's your culprit. You can continue testing it to see if only a part of it is responsible for the whole thing, I'm just illustrating the concept here. Usually a few removals show quite clearly where the problem lies. Basically your problem is somewhere in the head, my nr1 suspect is that polygon-transition effect that follows the mouse everywhere.

Anyway, have fun inspecting!